# How to remove the duplicate seond value in a RDD[(Int,Int)] and keep the one of the first value in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD like below:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array((1,2),(2,3),(4,5),(5,2),(4,3)))
```

which is `RDD[(Int,Int)]` I want to remove some duplicate value based on the second element in this tuple.It does not matter what the first element will remain in the result,the only thing is to remove duplicated second value.
In this example,the result can be:

```
(1,2)
(2,3)
(4,5)
```

or

```
(5,2)
(4,3)
(4,5)
```

or else, because the second element 2,3 is duplicated.However,The result must contains (4,5) since it is only one 5(second element) in this rdd.

So how should I do to obtain this? Something like .unique() or reduceByKey()?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your input missing something here? I don't see a duplicate there or am I missing how are you defining duplicates

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the second integer to key and use reduceByKey and switch them back. Something like this.

```
val rdd1 = ps.sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(Array((1,2),(2,3),(4,5),(5,2),(4,3)))
val rdd2 = rdd1.map(x => (x._2, x._1)).reduceByKey((x, y) => x).map(x => (x._2, x._1))
```

The results looks like this.

```
rdd2.collect().foreach(println)
(2,3)
(4,5)
(1,2)
```

Hope this helps.